# How to take input in expected form in java?

Tags: java, input, io, scanf

I want to take a string input in

```
%d+%d
```

format in java.How do i do it?

I know that I can do this with string.split() method. But I feel that it is going to be way more complex if I had to deal with more strings in input. Like

```
%d+%d-%d
```

I am looking for solutions that are close to a scanf solution for c.

I tried this for %d+%d

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scanner.next();
String first,second;
String[] arr = str.split("\\+");
first = arr[0];
second = arr[1];
scanner.close();
```

And this for %d+%d-%d+%d..........=%d-%d+%d.....+%d...

```java
private final String[] splitLoL(String txt) {
        LinkedList<String> strList1 = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> strList2 = new LinkedList<String>();
        LinkedList<String> strList3 = new LinkedList<String>();;
        strList1.addAll(Arrays.asList(txt.split("\\+")));

        for(String str : strList1) {
            String[] proxy = str.split("-");
            strList2.addAll(Arrays.asList(proxy));
        }
        for(String str : strList2) {
            String[] proxy = str.split("=");
            strList3.addAll(Arrays.asList(proxy));
        }
        String[] strArr = new String[strList3.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            strArr[i] = new String(strList3.get(i));
        }
        return strArr;
    }
```

Comment: You should probably remove all the spaces from the string before you apply the above.

Comment: @alfasin Ah, you are right, didn't notice that while posting

Comment: Now, this code will parse the example above splitting it to two tokens: "%d" and "%d-%d" - is that what you want?

Comment: @alfasin no, i just did it for my problem (%d+%d). I am wondering what to do for %d+%d-%d-%d+%d=%d/%d...... I can do that alright, but it becomes more complex than I want

Comment: You probably want to parse the string _recursively_, applying the split both by + and - as long as the string includes them respectively. You can get the idea from the python code here: https://alfasin.com/2015/08/05/a-simple-calculator-in-python/

Comment: @alfasin thanks, I wrote a function but that does not work recursively.

Comment: You'll have to make it either recursive or iterative in order for it to work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just to read the numbers? Or it matters on which side of the '=' are they?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = scanner.nextLine();
List<String> str2 = new ArrayList();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
  str2.add(m.group());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do the following using JDK 9+:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTrial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(" 4   z zz   ggg 22  e");

        scanner.findAll("\\d+").forEach((e) -> System.out.println(e.group()));
    }
}
```

This would print

> 4 22